# How to detect is VoIP call Running on Android?

Tags: android, voip

How to detect is VoIP call Running on Android now as
Viber/Skype/WhatsApp call how i can do it programmatically in android ?

```
public static boolean isVoip(Context context){ AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
if(manager.getMode()==AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION)
{ 
return true; 
} 
else
{ 
return false;
} 
}
```

Comment: can you show us your code and tell us what you have tried up till now

Comment: `public static boolean isVoip(Context context){
   AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
   if(manager.getMode()==AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION){
         return true;
   }
   else{
       return false;
   }
}`

Comment: so what is the error or problem that you are facing?

Comment: i don't know when incoming call over VoIP any time to stop my music player and when call finished run my player again , How to detect is VoIP call Running now when user using any app as Viber/Skype/WhatsApp/messenger ?

Comment: there is no such a thing as VoIP call in Android. VoIP call is just transmission of audio data from and to the device, and it is processed same way as audio stream listening, sound recording, etc. So you can't detect something that Android doesn't know about.

Comment: Any solution for this issue nowadays?